# Retrieving a website with added user input

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I read that to retrieve a webpage in java, it is quick to use:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
// read the contents using an InputStreamReader
```

But how would I add a variable given by the user into the url? For example:

User inputs x
Loads page http://example.com/x.php

I'm new to java, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as much as i remember it was possible to concatenate two strings in Java, cant you use this technique? 
url + inputString into an new URL variable, does it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
URL urlWithInput = new URL("http://example.com" + input);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");   
connection.connect();       
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Or

```
String url = "http://example.com" + "/" + input
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
URL urlWithInput = new URL(url);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");   
connection.connect();       
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Ah... you've made a bit more sense of it for me. Which one would you recommend I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation like this :

```
final String url = "http://example.com" + "/" + userInput
```

Then you can instantiate the URL with that string.

Comment: Cheers for the fast response, i'll be back with more questions soon :D